# Input group field check click handler on the entire input group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently trying to make an entire Bootstrap input-group to be able to clickable so that the checkbox will be clicked when any part of the input-group is clicked, and it should be able to uncheck the checkbox as well when the input-group is clicked. The current code I have working right now is this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.input-group,#opt_in').click(function(){
    if ($('#opt_in').is(':checked')) {
      $('#opt_in').prop('checked', false);
    }
    else{
      $('#opt_in').prop('checked', true);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <div class="input-group-text">
      <input type="checkbox" name="opt_in" id="opt_in" value="true">
      <label class="form-check-label">I CONFIRM</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with checkbox" id="consent">that all of my info is accurate and consent to be called as provided above</p>
</div>
```

But for some reason that I am unaware of, it's not working. Any reason why? I'm using jQuery here but I can also use vanilla javascript. I'm just not sure where my code is freaking out!

Comment: Just to get it out of the way.  You do realize that the label has a `for` attribute you can give it of the id you want to associate it with, and then clicking the label will toggle the element automatically, right?

Comment: It's working fine [here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/MBvapg). Did you load jQuery and Bootstrap?

Comment: Firstly if your code shows $ is undefined then u must put correct js file for it to recognize '$' i.e. jquery. Try Adding this :`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`